# Assign a new (default) struct to a current struct

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

System verilog allows defining a structure type with variable initialization. That's is when I declare a struct type, the struct's members are already initialized. I was wondering if there is a way to redeclare already existing struct with a new struct of the same type so that if any members were modified, they will be reset to their default values? Similar like it would be done for a class constructor `new Class()`.

```
typedef struct {
 int var1 = 1;
 int var2 = 2;
} my_struct_t;

my_struct_t myStruct;  // myStruct.var1 and myStruct.var2 already initialized
print(myStruct.var1);  // prints 1
print(myStruct.var2);  // prints 2

myStruct.var1=3;
myStruct.var2=4;
print(myStruct.var1);  // prints 3
print(myStruct.var2);  // prints 4

myStruct = default of my_struct_t;  // HOW???
print(myStruct.var1);  // prints 1
print(myStruct.var2);  // prints 2
```

In other words, I would like to reset the variables without the need of explicitly re-assigning the members with the default values or creating a method that would do so. This is to avoid maintaining two places where the defaults are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is by creating another variable, and qualifying with `const`,

````
module top;
  
  typedef struct {
    int var1 = 1;
    int var2 = 2;
  } my_struct_t;
  
  const my_struct_t  my_struct_default; 
  my_struct_t        myStruct;
  
  initial begin
    myStruct.var1=3;
    myStruct.var2=4;
    myStruct = my_struct_default;
    $display("%p", myStruct);
  end
endmodule
```
````

Comment: Dave - thank you. That will do it!